48V to 12V dc stepdown using TIP35C and 7812
From rectififer output of telecom equipments, 48V DC, I want to convert it to 12V DC. I'm considering this schematic:

Can this schematic convert 48V dc to 12V dc? Please recommend me for corrections.

It can work for low currents but wastes 75% energy in heat, so only use for low linear power

Telcom typically uses -48 V, so make sure you take the polarity into account. If it is a -48 V system you could have +12 V referenced to telcom ground, -12 V referenced to telcom ground, or either of those referenced to -48 V.

What current will the load demand?

I'd be reaching for an LM2594HV  or a more modern replacement.

The TIP35 is a power transistor, but the chosen resistor values (22kΩ and 10kΩ) may not provide sufficient base drive to handle higher currents.

It's -48V system, there is two busbar, one is -48V and another one is +Ve . I want to put input in LM2576HV, it can handle input upto 60V, How can I put input from telecom  rectifier system to LM2576HV?

It will typically work to provide 12V at the output as shown, though the headroom is rather small.
If you draw much current from the 12V output it will cease to regulate. Increasing the voltage divider unloaded voltage and changing Q1 to a Darlington would help, but this is a pretty nasty way to get 12V if you need much current (less than 25% efficiency and wastes hundreds of mW even with no output).



Please recommend me for corrections.

An LM7812 is rated to deliver up to 1.5 amps at its output and still regulate at 12 volts. But, it's a linear regulator and whatever arrangement you stick in front of it to reduce the maximum input voltage it's still going to drop voltage whilst passing up to 1.5 amps.
In other words, a linear regulator arrangement that can supply 1.5 amps at 12 volts from a 48 volt supply will drop 36 volts and dissipate a heat power of up to 54 watts. Even with a 0.5 amp load the whole arrangement is going to dissipate 18 watts and, I'm convinced that this is not what you want so, choose a buck regulator because it can have over 95% power efficiency and barely get warm.
That is the corrective recommendation I am making.
